# Closed linear operators and equality on a core

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $E$ be a Banach space and assume that $L_1 : D(L_1) = E \rightarrow E$, $L_2 : D(L_2) \subset E \rightarrow E$, $L_3 : D(L_3) \subset E \rightarrow E$ are closed linear operators and $D(L_2)$, $D(L_3)$ are dense in $E$. Assume that
$$
L_1 + L_2 : D(L_2) \rightarrow E, \quad f \mapsto L_1 f + L_2 f
$$
is again a closed linear operator.

Now let $C \subset D(L_2) \cap D(L_3)$ be a core for $(L_1, D(L_1)=E)$, $(L_2, D(L_2))$ and $(L_3, D(L_3))$ such that
$$
L_3 f = L_1 f + L_2 f \quad \forall f \in C.
$$

> Is it true that $(L_3, D(L_3)) = (L_1+L_2, D(L_2))$?

We clearly have
$$
(L_1 + L_2) f = L_1 f + L_2 f \quad \forall f \in D(L_2) \tag{1}
$$
and
$$
L_3 f = L_1 f + L_2 f \quad \forall f \in C \subset D(L_2) \cap D(L_3) \tag{2}.
$$
But is the equality on the core $C$ sufficient to conclude that $(L_3, D(L_3)) = (L_1+L_2, D(L_2))$? What if we assume that $C$ is dense in $E$?

---

Edit: It seems that the answer is positive, if $C$ is also a core for $(L_1+L_2, D(L_2))$? But is this necessarily the case?